# Automatic time adjustment is vastly off (7 hours)

Tags: date, time, xubuntu, ntp, timezone

Desktop environment: XFCE, Distro: Xubuntu 16.04 64-bit, Theme: Greybird

[image]

I am vacationing in Paris and my time is completely wrong. This is what my Time and Date settings look like. However, as of writing this, it is 10:20 PM in Paris and my system clock reads 03:20 PM. How can I make the time adjust properly?

One option is manually specify the time, but I would rather not manually specify the time everywhere I go since I will be traveling between many timezones, I expect my computer to be able to set the time.

Comment: Did you adjust the timezone and _also_ adjust the hardware clock?

Comment: What do you mean? I want my laptop to be able to adjust its own clock to match the time.

Comment: Set the hardware clock to UTC.  Tell the kernel you have done so.  Use the Time and Date Settings dialog depicted above to configure `/etc/localtime`.

Comment: As you are using a Debian based distribution, will suggest you to reconfigure using `dpkg` - `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`. This will do everything you need "under the hood"...

Comment: After running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, here's the output: `Local time is now:      Mon Jun 12 22:32:05 CEST 2017.`
`Universal Time is now:  Mon Jun 12 20:32:05 UTC 2017.` But the clock in the bottom-right corner of my screen, XFCE's clock, still says 03:33 PM. My clock configuration is `%a, %Y-%b-%d, %I:%M %p`

Comment: maybe you have wrong timezone for xfce? watch [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23218/how-to-add-a-custom-timezone-clock-to-an-xfce-panel)

Comment: Orage clock in that guide shows the correct time. but doesn't seem to have transparency, is there no way to fix the XFCE clock? https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/clock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I've found:

1. After running the suggested commands and looking through guides, the problem seems to only solve itself after awhile, it takes a lot of time. [Sounds like a job for Bender.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZzZ4mZipyM) So, patience!
2. XFCE clock and the system time are not synced. While system time was correct, XFCE clock was wrong until the problem solved itself awhile later.
3. Orage clock works better and finds the correct time faster but it doesn't support transparency.